# Hapi.js auth not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, hapi.js

This is my code now the problem here is when I am running this with hapi version 14.x.x or below it works for me perfectly fine but when I am running this with hapi version 15.0.1 or greater it gives me following error.

Is there any change in authentication process?

```
throw new Error(msgs.join(' ') || 'Unknown error');
    ^

    Error: Unknown authentication strategy UserAuth in /api/user/loginDetails
        at Object.exports.unique.exports.contain.exports.reachTemplate.exports.assert.condition [as assert] (F:\cbl\projects\lawn-mower\node_modules\hapi\node_modules\hoek\lib\index.js:736
    :11)
        at internals.Auth.test.internals.Auth._setupRoute (F:\cbl\projects\lawn-mower\node_modules\hapi\lib\auth.js:144:14)
```

Sample route that I am using

```
  {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/api/user/loginDetails',
        config: {
            auth: 'UserAuth',
            handler: function (request, reply) {
            },
            validate: {
                payload: {

                },
                headers: UniversalFunctions.authorizationHeaderObj,
                failAction: UniversalFunctions.failActionFunction
            },
            plugins: {
                'hapi-swagger': {
                    payloadType : 'form',
                    responses:Config.APP_CONSTANTS.swaggerDefaultResponseMessages
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

strategy I am using

```
server.register(require('hapi-auth-bearer-token'), function (err) {
    console.log("aaaaa");
    server.auth.strategy('UserAuth', 'bearer-access-token', {
        allowQueryToken: false,
        allowMultipleHeaders: true,
        accessTokenName: 'accessToken',
        validateFunc: function (token, callback) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What auth strategy are you using?

Comment: @simon-p-r edited my answer. But it works for me when I use hapi version less then 14.x.x or lower and when I upgrade the version to 15.x.x or 16.x.x it produces me the above error

Comment: @simon-p-r hey any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Try changing the string UserAuth to simple

Comment: @simon-p-r tried getting same error

Comment: It should not be the same error?  Error would be different

Comment: @simon-p-r thanks for help.The issue was not what we were looking in.Resolved and posted an answer for the same.

Comment: when are you loading the route and the strategy? Make sure to register the strategy before add the route to your server

Comment: @AdriVanHoudt yes got this have posted the answer for the same as welll in previous versions things were different which got changed in 15.x.x and above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved the issue for me  **plugin registrations are asynchronous** from hapi version 15.x.x or above

Explanation : In version 14.x.x or lower things go synchronously like when we will start the server it will find register the plugins first then it will go for routes **server.route(Routes)**.

This was fixed in hapi version 15.x.x and above now  **plugin registrations are asynchronous** so we need to register our plugins first then need to initialize the routes as in example below.

[Click here to get more details about it from latest updates thread no is 3295](https://hapijs.com/updates?limit=100)

```
  server.register(Plugins, function (err) {

        if (err){
            console.log("===========err=========",err)
            server.error('Error while loading plugins : ' + err)
        }else {
            console.log("====================");
            server.route(Routes);
            server.log('info','Plugins Loaded');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

this error occurs because you want to register a route that requires an authentication strategy which isn't available to the hapi server yet.

Make sure that the `UserAuth` strategy is registered before the route gets added to the server.

[This tutorial proposes 2 solutions](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-fix-unknown-authentication-strategy)

1. a dedicated authentication plugin which is used by your other hapi plugins as a dependency and therefore be available before adding routes
2. move the part where you're adding routes into the plugin registration callback and after the strategy definitions

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have only defined strategy, not scheme. So define your scheme like below code .

**You should try this:**

```
 var userFunc=function (server, options) {
     return {
        authenticate: function (request, reply) {
            console.log('UserAuth');
            return reply.continue({ credentials: { user: 'UserAuth'        } });
        }
    };
};

  server.auth.scheme('UserAuthScheme', userFunc);      // here
  server.auth.strategy('UserAuth', 'UserAuthScheme');  // here



  server.route([{
          method: 'POST',
          path: '/api/user/loginDetails',
          config: {
            auth: 'UserAuth',
            handler: function (request, reply) {
              reply('/api/user/loginDetails');
            },
            validate: {
              payload: {

              },
              headers: UniversalFunctions.authorizationHeaderObj,
              failAction: UniversalFunctions.failActionFunction
            },
            plugins: {
              'hapi-swagger': {
                payloadType: 'form',
                responses: Config.APP_CONSTANTS.swaggerDefaultResponseMessages
              }
            }
          }
        }]);
```

Comment: read the below answer it worked for me and have specified what was the exact issue and how it got resolved.